# Audio interface for ubuntu

Tags: sound, interface

I'm planning to make a video and audio editing system on Ubuntu. It is really difficult to match the need cause many hardware is not supporting softwares and drivers for ubuntu. At least audio interfaces should be well supported on ubuntu really this is the last resort. Supporting Every gear with usb connection with their own drivers and softwares won't be possible, but the audio interface is critical. What options do I have?? I glanced at the options through the internet, but they are all low quality or outdated. I hope Ubuntu support Arturia or UAD. Thanks for reading. Have a nice day:)